# Elastic search: Slow performance on large data set

Tags: elasticsearch, spark-streaming, bulkinsert

I have 7 node Elastic search cluster with 2 indices and both have nested object mapping. I am getting significant delay in insert to **Index2** (through spark streaming). I am using Bulk insert which takes ~8-12s per batch (~100k record).

```
Node Configuration:
RAM: 64 GB
Core: 48
HDD : 1 TB
JVM allocated Memory: 32 GB

Marvel Node Status:
CPU Usages: ~10-20%
JVM Memory: ~60-75%
Load Average    : ~3-35
Indexing Rate: ~10k/s
Search Rate: ~2k/s

Index1 (Replication 1): 
Status: green
Documents: 84.4b
Data: 9.3TB
Total Shards: 400 (Could it be the reason of low performance)

Index2 (Replication 1): 
Status: green
Documents: 1.4b
Data: 35.8GB
Total Shards: 10
Unassigned Shards: 0

Spark streaming configuration:
executors: 2
Executor core per executor: 8
Number of partition: 16
batch size: 10s
Event per batch: ~1k-200k
Elastic Bulk insert count: 100k
```

**Index2 mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": 5,
      "number_of_replicas": 1
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "parent_list": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
        "parents": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "parent_id": {
              "type": "integer",
              "doc_values": false
            },
            "childs": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "child_id": {
                  "type": "integer",
                  "doc_values": false
                },
                "timestamp": {
                  "type": "long",
                  "doc_values": false
                },
                "is_deleted": {
                  "type": "boolean",
                  "doc_values": false
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "other_ID": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "doc_values": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My query:**

1. Get count by parent ID with at least one child with is_deleted false.
2. Get count by child ID with is_deleted false.
3. Get documents by _id

I was expecting more performance from Elastic but it become bottleneck of my system. **Can someone suggest performance tuning? Can we achieve more insert rate from Elastic with this cluster configuration?**

Comment: 100k documents in a bulk batch does sound like a lot. Can you lower that and try again?

Comment: I tried with 10k as well but doesn't improve much

Comment: @AndreiStefan Index1 has 400 shards . Could it be the reason of low performance? What should be the expected insert rate?

Answer (score 1):

your problem is not at the configuration is probably at the hardware level.

try disabling throtling

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "indices.store.throttle.type" : "none" 
    }
}
```

turn off the replicas -> 0
lower the amount of shards to a maximum of 2-3 per node (400 is ridicusly dangerous)

change the refresh rate to -1 during indexation

```
PUT /{INDICE}/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "-1"
    }
}
```

load balance the bulk request among the servers (nodes)

use persistent conection through socket

make sure you're not running into a network bottleneck

regarding the 100k documents bulk request, it depends of the size of each document, a sweet spoot is always around 4-5k. WHY? because the bulk API do not insert the data right away, it first cache it and then dump it in disk, if you fulfill your cache sending too big batches you re gonna run into throtling issues.

if you're ussing persistent conections, you dont need to worry about the size of your bulk api, you could just open a socket and start sending batches of 1 document, it will be as fast as doing them in bluk. (as it doesnt need to handle the helo everytime which saves you 50ms per round trip)

any other question i know this is a bit late but hopefully someone finds it usefull a somepoint